# Duplicate key error when updating virtusertable.db in sendmail

Tags: linux, sendmail

In my virtusertable I have the following entry:

```
@fax.mydomain.com mail2fax.sh
```

Now I also want to forward *all* the inbound mail to another external domain while keeping my current setup, so I did this :

```
@fax.mydomain.com mail2fax.sh
@fax.mydomain.com @externaldomain.com
```

But when doing `makemap hash virtusertable.db < virtusertable` this error appears :

```
makemap: virtusertable.db: line 2: key @fax.mydomain.com: duplicate key
```

The destination mails will be *random* fax numbers like `0044555441122@fax.mydomain.com` so I can't use username based forwarding.

So I guess it is not possible to have duplicate entries for the inbound domain.
How would you do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a double key entry in *virtusertable*. You can do what you want for specific accounts by using both *virtusertabe* and *aliases*:

In *virtusertable*:

```
user1@fax.mydomain.com user1-fax
```

In *aliases*:

```
user1-fax: user1@externaldomain.com, "|mail2fax.sh"
```

Now run `make virtusertable` and `newaliases` and you are all set.

**UPDATE:**

Since the FAX numbers change rapidly, you can try installing [MIMEDefang](http://www.mimedefang.org) and call add_recipient() from within the [filter_recipient](http://linux.die.net/man/5/mimedefang-filter) function. This way you can add and delete the local and external recipients that you need. You may need to modify mail2fax.sh too.

Comment: I can't do that since users are not really usernames but fax numbers, so I can't really specify usernames. I will update my question.

Comment: Usage of the word "user" is liberal here. If the FAX numbers are fixed and do not change rapidly over time, the proposed solution holds. If the word "user" bothers you, replace it with "number" and your are set.

Comment: I mean that fax numbers are not fixed, they change on a daily basis.

Comment: Updated my answer with one more suggestion.